# css without editing the surrounding HTML

Tags: html, css

The question is to use css to position and coloring the articles.

[Question description screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyCNT.png)

The original code provided:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Articles</title>
  <style>
    /* Write your CSS solution here (do not edit the surrounding HTML) */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <article>First</article>
  <article>Second</article>
  <article>Third</article>
  <article>Fourth</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it really possible to solve the question without distinguishing this four article tags? the only solution I came up with is to add 'class' attribute and position & coloring each of them accordingly, but this violates the rule that we cannot edit the surrounding HTML.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must assign id or class to each one of them so you can create css selectors for them. If you have just two elements then you can use article:first-child and article:last-child in css

Comment: thanks guys! nth-child is very useful in this scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot edit your html you could use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector like this:

```
body article:nth-child(1){background: red;}
body article:nth-child(2){background: blue;}
body article:nth-child(3){background: green;}
body article:nth-child(4){background: orange;}

body article{float: left; width:50%; padding-bottom: 50px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lczrmb0k/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `nth-child` attribute and reference each article by its position relative from parent. Meaning:

if you want to set a redcolor to first article your rule should be:

```
article:nth-child(1){color:red}
```

For second sibling:

```
article:nth-child(2){color:blue}
```

They all can be referenced by a number :)

You can even do more crazy stuff without editing your HTML, take a look [this article](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
article {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
article:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
article:nth-child(2) {
    background: orange;
}
article:nth-child(3) {
    background: tomato;
}
article:nth-child(4) {
    background: teal;
}
```

```html
<article>First</article>
  <article>Second</article>
  <article>Third</article>
  <article>Fourth</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```css
article:nth-child(2n){
  background-color: red;  
}
article:nth-child(2n+1){
  background-color: yellow;  
}
article:nth-child(3n){
  background-color: lightblue;  
}
article:nth-child(4n+3){
  background-color: lightgreen;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Articles</title>
  <style>
    /* Write your CSS solution here (do not edit the surrounding HTML) */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <article>First</article>
  <article>Second</article>
  <article>Third</article>
  <article>Fourth</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nth-child` css function.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

article {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 50vh;
}

article:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

article:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
}

article:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}

article:nth-child(4) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Articles</title>
</head>

<body>
  <article>First</article>
  <article>Second</article>
  <article>Third</article>
  <article>Fourth</article>
</body>
```